# div width using a css class in seperate css file

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a class to a div by using a separate css file.
For instance, I have this in my html file:

```css
/* width 90% */

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  div.width90 {
    max-width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="width90">
  text in div with a 90% width
</div>
```

But it doesn't work... even if I strip the @media (min-width: 960px) it won't work either.

I've googled quite some time, but can't find the answer (and I'm not really familiar with this)

My goal of using this class is to show the text in a 90% width div block, but only on screens larger than 960px.

If I use this styling in the html, it works for every screen size, that's why I wanted to add it in a class:

```html
<div style="width: 90%">
  text in div with a 90% width
</div>
```

What should be the correct code to use? I hope I made the issue clear enough! ;)

Thanks, Ellen

Comment: your code looks fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apeKbJ do you have any errors in your browser console? are other CSS rules being read?

Comment: Have you included your media query too high - ie have you got other styles overwriting it?  If you inspect the div element (right click, inspect element) does it have the media query width crossed out?

Comment: @MichaelCoker no, I don't have any errors (that I know of that is). And yes, other css rules are being read. It's just this one that's not working.

Comment: @Pete I'll check right now and give you a link, just a moment.

Comment: @Pete When I inspect the element, the whole class doesn't show up... I have no idea why...
This is the page: http://test.santosbikes.net/assortiment/lite-serie/travel-lite
Just below the large header 'Betrouwbare pakezel', you'll see the div (I've mentioned it in the text).

Comment: ok had a look and your div is 90% above 960 and 100% below - is this not what you are wanting

Comment: Yes @Pete it's exactly what I want. But the width is wider than the text below "Super chique alleskunner" > (text Frame details, het oog wil ook wat)"
That div has a style=width: 90% and is the exact width I would like for the other one. 
I hope you can still follow me ;)

Comment: And I've added the code @Sahil mentioned in the custom.css file. If the 90% width would work, the background should be red. On my mobile device I do have a blue background, so below 960px it seems to work. Above not.

Comment: ok, shoot me... all of a sudden it works? Cache issues maybe... 
I'll try to strip the margins on mobile a bit more, it's still too small on mobile. But I guess, the issue is resolved?

Comment: Seems to be - when you refresh always do a hard refresh to make sure everything is re-downloaded (ctrl + f5) - I still think your original code whould have worked - perhaps that was also caching issues

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed this in your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Hi Sankar, I'm not really sure what you mean by this. 

I do have other classes working with different viewports, but this one just doesn't seem to work. So, I guess something is overwriting it.

Comment: @ellenvand You cannot see the difference between viewport unless the above is in not your head tag. But i can see this tag in your website. its fine

Comment: Thanks @Sankar any idea what else could be the problem?

Answer (score -2):

I have made an example below clearly explains what you have to do for this issue. The normal css will basically  run for all devices and the media query css will run for devices below 960px.

```css
/* Normal css for device greatee than 960px*/

.width90 {
  width: 90%;
  background: red;
  
}


/*custom  ResponsiveCss  for device less than 960px*/

@media (max-width:960px) {
  .width90 {
    width: 80%;/* Just specify the width you want for devices below 960px width*/
    background: blue;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="width90">
  Dummy Text
</div>
```

After checking the provided link by her . Here is the answer.
**You have missed one class in the width90 div section**. The parent of width90 is div with class **uk-panel** and after checking the full structure of similar section , I noticed you have missed class **uk-panel-box** with **uk-panel**.
So replace.

```
<div class="uk-panel " align="center">
```

to

```
<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box" align="center">
```

Rest my media query code is running.. Below 960px devices the width will be 100% as specified and above it will be 90%.

Comment: how is this any different to what the OP has done - apart from you seem to have changed min width to max width

Comment: The only difference, Pete, is that he uses a smarter and more stable way, by applying a media query to max-widths, and defining a "default" behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelDiPrisco Still doesn't answer the question of why the OP's code isn't working

Comment: OP didn't provide enough instruments to give a proper answer. In fact me and @Sahil Dhir gave a similar answer. It can't be answered as we have no resources to provide an answer, but we both pointed out a mistake that could potentially avoid future problems, and I think it should be welcomed, and not downvoted.

Comment: @MichaelDiPrisco And there you have it *"OP didn't provide enough instruments to give a proper answer. "*  So don't answer.  Ask for more details like Michael Coker and I did and once you have enough details, then answer the question

Comment: @Pete the person who has asked the question clearly wrote he is not much familiar to this. So in my answer  I was just educating him how to do this task more properly and efficiently so he can become familiar to this.

Comment: Hi guys, he is a she by the way ;) 

So, yes, I would love to give more instruments. I'll check the questions and try to answer it to my best knowledge.

Comment: @SahilDhir I tried your code, but it doesn't work. In both cases I can see it switching from 90% to 100% while loading. So, I guess something is overwriting it, but I can't find out what that is. 
This is the page: http://test.santosbikes.net/assortiment/lite-serie/travel-lite
Just below 'Betrouwbare pakezel' (huge title) you'll see the div I'm trying to use this class with.

Comment: @ellenvand the width its picking up is 90% only.. But i jsut checked the structural code of your site a div is missing  in that particular width 90 section.. Do you have skype or hangouts? I will give you the fix.

Comment: Just edited my answer and given you the solution. If you need any help on that do poke me. :)

Comment: Did you got the fix?

Comment: Hi @SahilDhir sorry for the late reply, but I'm working on it now. 
I noticed in Chrome it's not working, while in FF and Safari it works fine. Or maybe it's a caching thing again?
But, I haven't checked the fix you've suggested yet. I'll do that now. ;)

Comment: @SahilDhir yes, it was a caching issue with Chrome ;) 
For me everything works fine now, even without the uk-panel-box, so I'm happy (for now ;) ) 
Thanks everyone for your help, could not have resolved it without your help.